# jwplayer with vimeo plugin

Tags: jwplayer, vimeo

We had been using an older version of JWPlayer and the vimeo plugin w/o issue for a year or so, but it just stopped working.  So, now I'm trying to move to the latest versions of both...but I can't get them to work either.

I've been trying to get this plugin (https://sourceforge.net/projects/jwplayervimeo/) to work with the latest JWPlayer (5.10)

Here is my test, but it just spins and never plays the video

http://encoded.skateboard.tv.s3.amazonaws.com/dogboarding.htm

Did something change on Vimeo's end recently that is causing this?

Comment: I fixed an issue that was bugging me for 2 hours, only thanks to your post. So thanks a lot (especially for keeping that link up)! A good thing would be, if you ever plan to take the page down, to post the JavaScript code here, in your post. Maybe it will help others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for whatever reason, this plugin just started working again...must have been an intermittent issue with Vimeo